# Monitor I am using is keep showing input signal out of range. (Raspberry-pi4) How can I fix it?

Tags: display, signal

I am currently connecting my raspberry-pi4 to Hanns.G monitor. The monitor's display looks fine just except the message about **INPUT SIGNAL OUT OF RANGE**. This message is located at the center of my monitor display and I cannot get rid of it.

The monitor have a resolution setup with 1366x768.

First, I tried using start->preference->screen configuration->right click and change resolution. However, there was no 1366x768. I tried all the options which raspberry-pi 4 offers, however, I could not remove this message.

Next thing I did was changing config.txt. I removed # from #hdmi_safe=1, #overscan_left=16, #overscan_right=16, #overscan_top=16, #overscan_bottom=16 and I changed framebuffer_width=1366 framebuffer_height=768 (Of course I removed comments!), however, I could not remove that message! Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: That is a problematic resolution for a Pi4 https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=266440

Comment: So is there clear solution? The comments to that page shows different solutions!